# HQL Query for simple SQL joins

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

how can i apply 2 conditions in join in HQL
I want to write HQL for below query

```
Select * from Employee e
left join fetch Salary s on s.sal in (1000,2000);
```

My question is: how can we apply multiple conditions on join. i know internally, 
the query will be executed like

```
select * from Employee e
left join Salary s on s.id = e.id
```

but how can i write hql for more than single condition?
I hope my question is cleared?

Comment: What does your raw SQL query look like?

Comment: sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h");
  sb.append(" left join fetch h.hwCategory4 c4");
  sb.append(" left join fetch c4.hwCategory3 c3");
  sb.append(" where h.konto.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1");
  sb.append(" and h.technischeNr is not null");
  sb.append(" and upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3");
  sb.append(" and h.lifecycleSubStat.lcSubStatId not in ( ");
  sb.append(Constants.HARDWARECOMPONENT_STATE_ID_CLOSING);
  sb.append(")");

  rtn = cachingHibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(sb.toString(), params,
    values);

Comment: I know JPA/hibernate handles ON condition internally
but what if I want one more condition with ON
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Perviously I just gave an example to find out hql for multiple conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid HQL query would look something like this:

```
select e, s 
from Employee e left join e.salary s with (s.sal in (1000,2000))
```

This assumes that the `Employee` entity has a `Salary` field `salary`.  If I have the names off, then change the query.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong.  Based on the HQL documentation, this should work.

Comment: I am using left join fetch
Will it work for fetch also?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but if you are asking whether adding `fetch` would break the query, I would expect it would not.

Comment: I am getting below exception while using 'with'
•An unexpected error occured. Details: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters

Comment: This is my hibernte query in java class.

`StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h ");
  sb.append(" left join fetch h.hwCategory4 c4 with (upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3) ");
  sb.append(" left join fetch c4.hwCategory3 c3 with (h.konto.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1)  ");
  sb.append(" where ");
  sb.append("  h.technischeNr is not null ");`

Comment: This is completely different than the question you posted.  You should ask a new question.